# Разница между приложением и апплетом?

Tags: java, swing

В книге Swing.Руководство для начинающих говорится: "...иерархия должна начинаться с контейнеров верхнего уровня. В **приложениях** для этой цели чаще всего используют объект JFrame, а в **апплетах** - JApplet. "

Не могли бы вы прояснить конкретную разницу/назначение этих двух понятий ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Различия можно прочитать [тут](https://way2java.com/applets/applets-vs-applications/), по сути `Application` это самостоятельное приложение, которое можно запустить в системе с `JVM`, а `Applet` это аналог, который запускается с помощью дополнительных средств, например браузера.